# Unexpected results when creating selector from code and not from xml

Tags: android, listview, android-xml, statelistdrawable

I'm having some trouble converting some working XML files into code.
I have a ListView, and I need to be able to switch its pressed/checked drawables at run-time, from resources not known in advanced (hence why not using XML);

The following configuration works great:

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/green" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/orange"/>
</selector>
```

list_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selector"
    android:padding="10dp" />
```

Main.java:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    StateListDrawable selector; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        StringAdapter adapter = new StringAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row);
        adapter.add("one");     adapter.add("two");     adapter.add("three");       adapter.add("four");
        adapter.add("five");        adapter.add("six");     adapter.add("seven");       adapter.add("eight");
        adapter.add("nine");        adapter.add("ten");     adapter.add("eleven");      adapter.add("twelve");
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class StringAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        public StringAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);         
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final CheckedTextView  tv = (CheckedTextView ) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
            tv.setText(getItem(position));
            return tv;
        }
    }
}
```

The result is like this, which is great (pressed:blue, checked:green, else:orange):

[image: result1]

However, if I remove the

```
android:background="@drawable/selector
```

from list_row_xml, and apply it via code:

```
    Drawable blue = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue);
    Drawable green = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green);
    Drawable orange = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.orange);

    selector = new StateListDrawable();
    selector.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, blue);
    selector.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_checked }, green);
    selector.addState(new int[] { }, orange);

       tv.setBackgroundDrawable(selector);
```

I get the following (everything get the state_pressed drawable, blue):

[image]

What went wrong? I'm pretty sure I converted the selector to code appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I copied your code and it all works fine.
You should make sure to create a new instance of `selector` in `getView()` though. Otherwise if you use the same `selector` for all your items, pressing one item will affect all your items.

Here's what your `getView()` method should look like

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final CheckedTextView tv = (CheckedTextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
        tv.setText(getItem(position));

        Drawable blue = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue);
        Drawable green = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green);
        Drawable orange = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.orange);

        selector = new StateListDrawable();
        selector.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, blue);
        selector.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_checked }, green);
        selector.addState(new int[] {}, orange);

        tv.setBackgroundDrawable(selector);

        return tv;
    }
```

Of course there is some optimization you could do, but this will work.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, works perfectly! Though I don't understand why...Can you please explain? :)

Comment: My guess is that you added you last block of code in the onCreate method, thus only instantiating `StateListDrawable selector` once.
If in `getView()` you do `tv.setBackgroundDrawable(selector);` this will add exactly the same `StateListDrawable` to all your TextViews. Changing the state of one View will then also update the states of all your other views.

Comment: btw. I'm not sure my explanation is 100% correct. But I have had similar problems and always solved them by creating new instances in getView()

Comment: Well, It does make sense in some level :)